# How to get a .txt file of all folders names inside a folder but not the files/subfolders inside the child folders using powershell?

Tags: list, powershell, directory, names

Currently I'm using, SHIFT + Right Click > Open powershell window here > then paste in

```
dir -recurse | select -ExpandProperty Name | foreach {$_.split('.',2)[0]} | out-file file.txt
```

Only problem is I choose a directory to SHIFT + Right click, but I get all the names of the files/folders inside the second folder too and it really ruins the organization I'm going for.

So for example I have a folder called "RootFolder".
Inside RootFolder is 10 other folders called "Folder1" through "Folder10".
I only want the names Folder1 - Folder10 to be inside a .txt folder the shell command creates. I do not want Subfolders/files inside folders Folder1-10 in the .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only list directories you need to tell it.

```
Dir -R | ? { $_.PSIsContainer }
```

or

```
Dir -R | ? { $_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] }
```

In more recent PowerShell versions you can do it directly.

```
Dir -Dir
```

`Dir` = Get-ChildItem
`-R` = -Recurse
`?` = Where-Object
`-Dir` = -Directory

Answer (score 0):

If you only want directories within the named directory, you don't want to recurse. That will travel the entire directory hierarchy; just use the -Directory switch to filter the output to only include directories.

Then, you can just extract the Name property from the DirectoryInfo objects.

```
PS C:\> dir C:\Windows -Directory |% { $_.Name }
addins
appcompat
apppatch
AppReadiness
[...]
```

and output as desired. Even more concisely:

```
(dir C:\Windows -Directory).Name
```